# application analytic

Tags: analytics

I have mtiks a mobile analytic software in my application and I want know if I have to inform the user that I use it or can I ignore it? Do I get lawproblems or is my application not accepted?

Thanx
newone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no requirement to show a disclaimer in the app itself, you can include it in your apps EULA. More details for a Google Analytics example here: http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-way-to-inform-our-iPhone-App-users-that-we-use-Google-Analytics-to-track-their-usage